# Overriding Model.parse When Using Collection.reset

Tags: backbone.js

I need to use `Model.parse` to change the structure of incoming JSON; I also need to feed data into my collection using `Collection.reset` (we're drawing data from a plugin, not directly from a server).  After a lot of effort, it seems to me that `parse` is only called when `Collection.fetch` is used, and not when passing data with `reset` or when feeding the JSON directly into the collection constructor ([the documentation appears to agree](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse)).

**Is there some way to force Backbone to pass the raw model object to `parse` for all cases in which new data is fed to it?**

Right now I'm processing the raw object model in a separate function before passing it to `reset`, and while this does work, I find it to be a pretty unsatisfying solution. I'm also *incredibly* new to Backbone, so I'm vaguely suspicious that I'm just misunderstanding the relation between `parse`/`reset`/`fetch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the purpose of `reset` is to load a collection with either fully fledged Models or raw model attribute hashes which would be why `parse` is not invoked.

Your workaround doesn't really sound that bad to me in theory. The way I would do that is to run the data I wanted to put in the collection through the underscore.js `map` function which is a good fit for this usecase in my opinion.

Consider the code in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3m0TAMpdZweSnhUtWj6x?p=preview)

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    parse: function(data) {
      return {
        text: data.text.toUpperCase() 
      }
    }

});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: MyModel

});

var collection = new MyCollection();

var arr = [
  { text: 'abc' },
  { text: 'cde' }
];


collection.reset(arr);
console.log(collection.pluck('text'));

collection.reset(_.map(arr, MyModel.prototype.parse));
console.log(collection.pluck('text'));
```

There's a `MyModel` with a `parse` function, and two ways of resetting a collection made for that model. The second approach uses `_.map` instead of just passing the raw data. The [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) function takes an array and a function reference and returns a new array containing the objects of the input function transformed by the second argument, in this case that function is the model's `parse`.

If you still don't like that syntax you could try to provide a custom [Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) so it talks directly with the plugin you're getting data from instead of using a REST backend. That's a bit more work though and I personally don't think it's really worth the effort. You'd just end up doing pretty much the same thing but in a more contrived way but if you're also going to be handling deleting and updating data through the same plugin it's probably cleaner.

Comment: I guess it only really bothered me on a sort of purist level.  Backbone is so nicely organized and I liked the idea of not having to break paradigm.  Still, good info.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @SandyGifford I think overriding Sync would be the most purist way to do it as Sync is there to be overridden in the first place. And you could even make that a Backbone-plugin (like http://backplug.io/plugin/Backbone.localStorage) if the plugin you're getting data from is in common use.  I guess that would be more purist indeed but as you can see from the github repo of that plugin it's a bit more code required. If nothing else it would be a nice exercise in how Backbone.Sync works.

Comment: I agree entirely, but (and it kills me to say this) given the scope of this project, I don't think that I can justify that much work in the name of satisfying, awesome code.  Having said that, I think I will be returning to this later to implement something I can use in the future.